# How to use dynamic linq condition

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-web-api

using System.Linq.Dynamic.Core;

```
    public IActionResult GetList([FromBody] ListInput input)
    {
       
            var queryComponent = BuildWhereClause(input.Data);
            string whereClause = queryComponent.whereClause;
            string requiredAttribute = queryComponent.nextToLastNonNullValue;
            var result = ExecuteSqlQuery(whereClause, requiredAttribute);
            return new ObjectResult(result);
    }

   
    private dynamic BuildWhereClause(List<ListData> data)
    {
        List<string> conditions = new List<string>();
        string nextToLastNonNullValue = null;
        List<string> filteredRecord1 = null;
        foreach (var item in data)
        {
            var properties = item.GetType().GetProperties();
            Console.WriteLine(properties.Length);
            for (int i = properties.Length-1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                var value = properties[i].GetValue(item);

                if (value != null)
                {
                    if (nextToLastNonNullValue == null)
                    {
                        nextToLastNonNullValue = properties[i + 1].Name;
                    }
                }
            }

            foreach (var prop in item.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                var value = prop.GetValue(item);
                   if (value != null)
                {
                   string condition = $"{prop.Name} = '{value}'";
                    conditions.Add(condition);
                }
            }
        }

        if (conditions.Count == 0)
        {
            return (string.Empty, nextToLastNonNullValue);
        }

        string whereClause = string.Join(" AND ", conditions);
        return (whereClause, nextToLastNonNullValue);
    }

    private dynamic ExecuteSqlQuery(string whereClause, string requireAttribute)
    {

        string sqlQuery = $"SELECT * FROM jsons";

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(whereClause))
        {
            sqlQuery += $" WHERE {whereClause}";
        }

        var jsonModels = _jsonsContext.jsons.FromSqlRaw<JsonModel>(sqlQuery).ToList(); // fix this
        
        var attributes = requireAttribute.Split(',');

        var data = new Dictionary<string, List<object>>();

        foreach (var attribute in attributes)
        {
            var distinctValues = jsonModels.Select(model => GetPropertyValue(model, attribute)).ToList().Distinct().ToList();
            data[attribute] = distinctValues;
        }

        return new{data}
    }


    private object GetPropertyValue(JsonModel model, string propertyName)
    {
        var property = typeof(JsonModel).GetProperty(propertyName);
        if (property != null)
        {
            return property.GetValue(model);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

I'm working on an ASP.NET Core project where I need to fetch and filter data from a `jsonRecords` object based on dynamically generated conditions. The goal is to return a list of specific attributes from the filtered data. However, I'm encountering an issue with generating linq query.

Here's an overview of my code and the problem I'm facing:

1. I have a `JsonEditorContext` containing JSON data stored in a `jsons` DbSet.
2. I receive input conditions in the form of a `ListInput` object, which contains a list of `ListData` objects.
3. I use Dynamic LINQ to dynamically build a WHERE clause based on non-null values in the `ListData` objects. I also identify the last non-null attribute for later use.
4. I execute the SQL query with the generated WHERE clause and attempt to return specific attributes from the filtered data. but i want to fatch data from object not directly to database.

Any help or guidance on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: It seems to me, that you are generating SQL so I don't know what part of it is related to Dynamic Linq. And it is not obvious what part of it is not working or what is wrong or what the error is.

Comment: Your server is a controller.  You have a frontend where the client is serializing data  to json and putting json in to a HTTP body (contents) in client.  Then sending an HTTP request to server.  The server is then deserializing the json body and getting original data from json.  Backend of your controller/server is a connection from the server to database.  You do not need the backend.  You can take the deserialize json and do whatever processing you want.  Use the controller base class : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Comment: Side note: Your method of constructing the `WHERE` clause is open to a *SQL injection attack* or at least a syntax error if any of your values contain apostrophes. For example, of one of your intended filter conditions is last name = "O'Toole", the dynamic SQL `...AND Lastname = 'O'Toole' AND...` will fail with a syntax error.